# How do I save the current Canvas 2D state as a texture in memory, then render it later?

Tags: typescript, canvas, 2d, game-development

I'm using Canvas2D and the (CanvasRenderingContext2D)[https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D] in the web to make a game (using TypeScript). What I'm trying to achieve is saving the current state of the canvas render, similarly to a screenshot, and storing it in memory. I want this so that I can create a mini-map of my world, without overhead of re-rendering. Is this feasible, or does this require a WebGL renderer?
Couldn't find anything about this while googling around

Some psuedo-code of what I'm trying to achieve

```
//First we would render the world

//...

//Then save a render of the canvas
var texture = ctx.saveRenderOrSomeShit();

//Render hud

//...

//Render the world as part of the hud to top right or something similar

ctx.fillRect(texture, etc etc etc);

//Done rendering
```

Thanks for reading!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`ctx.drawImage()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/drawImage) does accept `HTMLCanvasElement` or `OffscreenCanvas` instances as input, so you could create one such canvas, draw there, and then use it as your texture:

```js
const texture = new OffscreenCanvas(50, 50);
const texCtx = texture.getContext("2d");
texCtx.fillStyle = "red";
texCtx.roundRect(0, 0, 50, 50, [30, 10]);
texCtx.fill();

const main = document.querySelector("canvas");
const ctx = main.getContext("2d");
main.addEventListener("mousemove", (evt) => {
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, main.width, main.height);
  const x = evt.clientX - main.offsetLeft - texture.width / 2;
  const y = evt.clientY - main.offsetTop - texture.height / 2;
  ctx.drawImage(texture, x, y);
});
ctx.drawImage(texture, 50, 50);
```

```css
canvas { border: 1px solid }
```

```html
<canvas></canvas>
```

However having one full canvas + 2D context per texture is a bit consumptive memory wise, so instead you could [create `ImageBitmap`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/createImageBitmap) objects from your canvas, but this is async, so you'd need to prepare them ahead of time.

```js
(async () => {
  const main = document.querySelector("canvas");
  main.width = 50;
  main.height = 50;
  const ctx = main.getContext("2d");
  ctx.fillStyle = "red";
  ctx.roundRect(0, 0, 50, 50, [30, 10]);
  ctx.fill();
  const texture = await createImageBitmap(main);
  main.width = 300;
  main.height = 150;
  main.addEventListener("mousemove", (evt) => {
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, main.width, main.height);
    const x = evt.clientX - main.offsetLeft - texture.width / 2;
    const y = evt.clientY - main.offsetTop - texture.height / 2;
    ctx.drawImage(texture, x, y);
  });
  ctx.drawImage(texture, 50, 50);
})();
```

```css
canvas { border: 1px solid }
```

```html
<canvas></canvas>
```

And since it seems that you were hoping to use this texture as a `fillStyle`, then note that you can also use a canvas as source for [`createPattern()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/createPattern):

```js
const main = document.querySelector("canvas");
main.width = 50;
main.height = 50;
const ctx = main.getContext("2d");
ctx.fillStyle = "red";
ctx.roundRect(0, 0, 50, 50, [30, 10]);
ctx.fill();
const texture = ctx.createPattern(main, "no-repeat");
main.width = 300;
main.height = 150;
ctx.fillStyle = texture;
main.addEventListener("mousemove", (evt) => {
  ctx.resetTransform();
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, main.width, main.height);
  const x = evt.clientX - main.offsetLeft - 50 / 2;
  const y = evt.clientY - main.offsetTop - 50 / 2;
  // Patterns position is always relative to the context's CTM
  // So we need to transform it rather than just using x, y of our path
  ctx.translate(x, y);
  ctx.fillRect(0, 0, 50, 50);
});
ctx.translate(50, 50);
ctx.fillRect(0, 0, 50, 50);
```

```css
canvas { border: 1px solid }
```

```html
<canvas></canvas>
```

Comment: Exactly the kind of thing I was looking for, and a great clear explanation. Thanks!